# Unable to start service intent,U=0: not found?

Tags: android, mqtt, android-source

I'm trying to run the MqttService Client from Paho in a System Service (AOSP) in android, but I receive following error:

```
970-01-01 01:00:18.794 2658-2658/system_process D/MqttClientService: Failed to connect to: tcp://localhost:1883 exception java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot start service org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService
1970-01-01 01:00:18.794 2658-2658/system_process W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.bindService:1649 org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.connect:425 com.android.server.MqttClientService.init:193 com.android.server.MqttClientService.<init>:127 com.android.server.SystemServer.startOtherServices:953 
1970-01-01 01:00:18.794 2658-2658/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=android/org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService } U=0: not found
```

What does U=0: not found found mean?

Comment: android/org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService can not be found. Did you declare org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService in the framework/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes i did declare it